# Forcing as a Quotient

Tags: logic, set-theory, forcing

I'm reading Jech and following his Boolean algebra models approach to it. I'm wondering if I've got the right idea here.

Let $M \models \mathrm{ZFC}$ and $B \in \mathbf{CompBoolAlg}$. We construct $M^B$ as follows:

- $M^B_0 = \emptyset$
- $M^B_{\alpha+1} = \{ \text{partial functions} \ f : M^B_\alpha \to B \}$
- $M^B_\Lambda = \bigcup_\lambda M^B_\lambda$ for limits $\Lambda$

and $M^B = \bigcup_\alpha M^B_\alpha$.

This gives an embedding of $B$ valued models
$$\begin{align} 
    \check{} : M &\to M^B \\
    \emptyset &\mapsto \emptyset \\
    x &\mapsto \{ \check y \mid y \in x \}
\end{align}$$

Now let $G$ be a generic ultrafilter on $B$. Is it the case that $M[G] = \check M / G$? Any help appreciated!

Comment: What's $\check M/G$?

Comment: $ \check M / G $ quotients by $ \check m \operatorname{mod}  G = \check n \operatorname{mod} G \iff \| \check m = \check n \| \in G $ and is a 2 valued model under $ \check m \operatorname{mod} G \in \check n \operatorname{mod} G \iff \| \check m \in \check n \| \in G $.

Comment: The equality of check-names is independent of the choice of $G$. So $\check M/G=M$.

Comment: Thank you that is definitely right. Is it the case that $M[G] = M^B/G$?

Comment: @ASheard Yes. (Or they’re isomorphic, anyway.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thanks! I'm wondering one more thing: when $G$ is _not_ generic, as Asaf pointed out, $\check M / G = M$ nonetheless. What happens to $M^B / G$ that makes things... I don't know, `bad'?

Comment: @ASheard $M^B/G$ need not be well-founded in that case. But in terms of extracting relative consistency results, nothing bad happens… genericity (or even quotienting down to a two-valued model) is not necessary for that.

Comment: @ASheard $M^B/G$ is always a model of ZFC, regardless of whether $G$ is generic or not.  However, if $G$ is not generic, $M^B/G$ will not be a forcing extension of $M$ but of some larger model (essentially the model of all "names that look like check names"). See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.6075) by Hamkins and Seabold.

Comment: @Asheard for an explicit, if a bit trivial example, when $B$ is a power set algebra, the quotient is isomorphic to the ultrapower. So if $G$ is an ultrafilter that is not countably complete, it won’t be well-founded. (This is covered in the paper I see Miha just provided.)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Thank you for this example! I've got one more question - so when $ G \in M $ already, we have $M^B / G = M$... I can't think of a simple reason I should have expected this to be true?

Comment: @ASheard Not necessarily. Like Miha said, if $G$ is not generic (i.e. non-principal in this power set case), $M^B/G$ is a forcing extension of an elementary extension $M'$ of $M,$ not of $M.$ In this example, $M'$ the ultrapower of $M$ by $G$, and indeed, $M^B/G=M'$ (i.e. the forcing extension is trivial), since $G\in M.$